# postgresql search case-insensitive with japanese character (full-width, halfwidth)

Tags: postgresql

In posgresSQL I can search insensitive with lower/upper character data (a/A)

But with japansese character in data how can I do that.
For example in data I have Name = "アアﾊﾞﾊﾞﾊﾞ"

How can I search with condtion Name = "アアアバババ" will return above record.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are two type of character in Japanese character : Full-width and half-width like lower and upper of anphabel character.
In postgresSQL can I make a custom convert function like toLower() or toUpper() which sql query ?

Comment: If you are using the proper locale and collation for your data, I would expect `lower()` to work properly. However Postgres uses the collation support from the operating system, so this largely depends on the implementation of your operating system then.

Comment: What PostgreSQL version are you using? `SELECT version()`. What operating system? Both are important. Also show the output of the queries `SHOW server_encoding;` `SHOW lc_collate;` `SHOW lc_ctype;`. On my Fedora 22 Linux system with UTF-8 encoding and `en_AU.UTF-8` locale `lower(..)` and `upper(..)` return the input string for the above unmodified.

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure the database is smart enough to do this, since as far as PostgreSQL (unicode) is concerned one string has six characters and the other has eight characters. It doesn't know how to do case conversions that change the number of characters; the concept of "case" gets hard to clearly define outside Roman-derived characters as used in English. You might need an extension function or plugin that knows the language rules for case transformations. BTW, you might have more luck if you ask on the pgsql-general mailing list, since a bunch of Japanese speakers are there.

Comment: Thanks all for your help、 I try this code and this work for me , but I didn't try with big data

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help、 I try this code and this work for me , but I didn't try with big data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION h2z_kana(text) 
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        zenkaku alias FOR $1;
        result text;
        i int;


        zt varchar[] = ARRAY['ガ', 'ギ', 'グ', 'ゲ', 'ゴ', 'ザ', 'ジ', 'ズ', 'ゼ', 'ゾ', 'ダ', 'ヂ', 'ヅ', 'デ', 'ド', 'バ', 'ビ', 'ブ', 'ベ', 'ボ', 'パ', 'ピ', 'プ', 'ペ', 'ポ', 'ヴ'];
        ht varchar[] = ARRAY['ｶﾞ', 'ｷﾞ', 'ｸﾞ', 'ｹﾞ', 'ｺﾞ', 'ｻﾞ', 'ｼﾞ', 'ｽﾞ', 'ｾﾞ', 'ｿﾞ', 'ﾀﾞ', 'ﾁﾞ', 'ﾂﾞ', 'ﾃﾞ', 'ﾄﾞ', 'ﾊﾞ', 'ﾋﾞ', 'ﾌﾞ', 'ﾍﾞ', 'ﾎﾞ', 'ﾊﾟ', 'ﾋﾟ', 'ﾌﾟ', 'ﾍﾟ', 'ﾎﾟ', 'ｳﾞ'];
    BEGIN


        result = zenkaku;


        -- 2バイトで変換
        FOR i IN 1..26 LOOP
            result = replace(result, ht[i], zt[i]);
        END LOOP;


        -- 1バイトで変換
        result = translate(result,
                   ' ｱｲｳｴｵｶｷｸｹｺｻｼｽｾｿﾀﾁﾂﾃﾄﾅﾆﾇﾈﾉﾊﾋﾌﾍﾎﾏﾐﾑﾒﾓﾔﾕﾖﾗﾘﾙﾚﾛﾜｦﾝｧｨｩｪｫｯｬｭｮﾜｲｴｶｹｰ､｡･｣｢ﾞ,<.>/?_}]*:+;{[~@|\\`^=-)(&%$#"!',
                   '　アイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワヲンァィゥェォッャュョヮヰヱヵヶー、。・」「゛，＜．＞／？＿｝］＊：＋；｛［￣＠｜￥｀＾＝－）（＆％＄＃"！'
              );


        RETURN result;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```